# Questions with strict or academic requirements/constraints

Tags: discussion, questions

I'd like to see how others feel about questions that have requirements/constraints that are so strict that the question may not be useful to others. I feel this tends to happen often with homework questions, but my concern isn't strictly about homework questions.

For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516840/2d-array-as-a-default-constructor-argument-c) could be solved quite trivially by storing members as `std::vector` and `std::string`, however the OP insists that they are not allowed to use those standard library classes.

Similarly I've stumbled across numerous questions where people insist they must `new[]` and `delete[]` arrays, and cannot use `std::vector`.

This happens in many languages as well, for example people claiming they "aren't allowed to `import` anything" in Python when `itertools` or `collections` would solve their problem robustly.

In these cases, while we could come up with solutions without those classes/modules/libraries/etc, it would be like trying to fight with your hands behind your back. In my opinion, the questions are too specific to the OP's situation and will not be helpful to those who find the question later on, as they should use a better solution since they do not have the same constraints.

**In summary:**
How should we handle questions with ad-hoc constraints/requirements?

Comment: None of your examples seem off-topic. They look like perfectly valid questions. If you are required to do something without using a library / function, then you are required to do that thing without using said library / function. If you don't like questions that ask you to do something without a library / function, don't look at those questions. They do not seem to be actively harmful to the community.

Comment: @TinyGiant I guess I'm not concerned about the questions being "harmful" per se, but rather "not useful to anyone but the OP"

Comment: And who says that they won't be useful? What's to say that no one else will ever be faced with those, or similar, limitations again? What's to say that nothing else can possibly be learned from the techniques used to get around the limitations?

Comment: "they are not allowed to use those standard library classes." they should get the heck out of that course... there isn't a slightly real world situation where you cannot use standard libraries; nobody should teach others how to reinvent the wheel, but how to use the damn wheel.

Comment: @Braiam *hollow, bitter laughter* In my entire career I have only encountered *one* production C++ application that used the C++ standard library.  All the others, and believe me there were plenty, flat-out forbade the use of the C++ standard library, in favor of their own hand-rolled class library.  (The situation is different in many other languages, of course, but your blanket statement requires only one counterexample.)

Comment: @zwol there's no internet meme that can express how sad I feel... SO I WILL WAIT SOMEONE CREATE ONE!

Comment: back in my day these used to be tagged with `homework`

Comment: [This has come up before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266979/264775), but "too localized" was still a close reason then (so the accepted answer doesn't apply 100% any more).

Comment: @thegrinner I like the first suggestion in the answer of that post. Essentially post the unconstrained solution first, then post the constrained  solution after, with comments for both solutions. Then if someone finds the question later on, it is clear that they don't have to use the constrained solution. Good find!

Comment: @Braiam "there isn't a slightly real world situation where you cannot use standard libraries" - I don't think this claim holds in a lot of embedded contexts.

Comment: @Angew how common is that the whole population of programmers has to work in embedded contexts? Yes, it doesn't holds true for all context, but it does for the most common ones... like 98% of so.

Comment: @Braiam At the same time, it *does* mean that such limitations are far from artificial, which gives such restricted questions their merit.

Comment: @Angew I'm not saying they don't have merit, just that the generality simply doesn't get beneficed of them and, more than anything, can cause confusion if isn't well explained the reasoning behind those constrains.

Comment: @Braiam The [tag:embedded] tag alone has 3k followers. I don't think we can dismiss embedded programming as "uninteresting minority." What would we dismiss then, maybe [tag:scheme] (1.9k followers)?

Comment: @Angew how many views have SO at large vs questions with those tags?

Answer (score 36):

[This happened to me back in April](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727758/1079354), and in all honesty, those sorts of restrictions/requirements can come up for *any* number of reasons, not just academic.

By and large, I've been answering those questions where and when it makes practical sense to do so.  If a solution clearly exists within the constraints, then I will endeavor to provide it.  If I don't think that a solution would make sense within their constraints, I occasionally provide an answer that violates their constraints *and* provide rationale as to why the other approach is impractical.

Comment: My biggest issue with such questions is when the original version of the question doesn't cite the constraints that the answers must deal with, but the OP gets stroppy when the answers don't match the constraints they didn't say had to be met.  That happens; it is frustrating.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  It definitely does happen and it definitely is frustrating; in those cases, I usually withdraw my answer and vote to close until the OP can better revise their original question to suit their actual problem.  No sense in both of us wasting our time because they forgot to mention a few constraints.

Answer (score 10):

This is where the issue with the old "Too Localized" close reason ran into problems.  Where is the dividing line between "useful only to 1 person" and "useful to the [programming] community".  Is something that can help 2 users ok?  Is something that can help only students ok?

I can see these types of constraints can come up in academic homework because the assignment is asking the students to try to walk before they run (i.e. understand why something works before they use the tools that do all of the work for them).

A question that is common enough to come up multiple times has to have some value to the community, even if it is just the academic community.  I don't see a problem with a solvable problem that has requirements that force the user to not make use of specific libraries.

Comment: "*I don't see a problem with a solvable problem*" that's art right there.