# Is it bad form to say what kind of replies you don't want?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If I am asking a question, and I am anticipating people answering with the *wrong* answer, is it bad form to put in my question, "Please don't reply with xxx answers"?

For example, I am painting my house using latex paint, and I ask about what shade of blue looks closest to water. Is it appropriate to ask in my question, "please don't reply with comparisons of latex to acrylic" because I know I am going to get multiple answers on that specific topic, and I want to avoid having to reply to all of them, well-intentioned as they may be?

I asked this elsewhere, but I wanted to get feedback on the main site since this applies to any site.

Comment: It depends on the specific case. In general there shouldn't be a problem with this, but I also often see people stating "I tried X and it didn't work, so please don't answer with that" although I know that X is the only good solution and that it for sure works in their case.

Comment: Related: [Questions with strict or academic requirements/constraints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313629/11682469)

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow isn't the "main forum". It's the Meta for Stack Overflow only. Meta Stack Exchange is the network-wide meta site.

Comment: You are basically dealing with a self-fulling prophecy here. If it is going to be written in such a way that you know it is going to attract off-topic answers, do you really think the question itself will be well-received? No, it'll be downvoted and possibly closed. It is in your own best interest to not let it happen to begin with.

Comment: To prove your point you could have added "Please don't reply with Yes as an answer"

Comment: Can you give a better example perhaps? It seems as if you just want to exclude some answers you do not *like* – that should not be a criteria, since other people with the same question might feel differently. On the other hand, if you want to exclude *wrong* answers, I am very dearly hoping that it is already understood implicitly by everybody that wrong answers are not okay.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried to be generic in my question. Since this question was closed, I don't see the need to expand. You can check out SharePoint.StackExchange for the actual question that prompted THIS question.

Comment: @Catija well, it's the meta for the largest forum (site? OK, site). I already received numerous responses here, and none on Meta SharePoint StackExchange, so my strategy worked. But thanks for letting me know about Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Using the StackOverflow Meta because you don't get an answer over at <other site> Meta is a bit like loosing your keys in the park but searching them under a streetlight. The answers you find here don't necessarily apply to the problem over there.

Comment: There are 6 question marks in your sharepoint.se post. Ask 1 specific clear question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use tags to indicate which kinds of answers you want and if that **isn't enough**, explain what you want in your question.

Indicating which answer you don't want is good and helpful for the answerers, because you would downvote the "wrong" answers as not helpful.

So if the explanation of which answers you want and need is **still not enough**, additionally write what you don't want in your question.

**In short**

1. Try to add the appropriate tags

If that isn't enough to explain what you want

2. Add an explanation of what you **do** want explicitly in your question

And if that still isn't enough to explain what you really want

3. Add what you **don't** want explicitly in your question.

Comment: The double (triple?) negation in your last statement is rather confusing. Could you clean that up slightly? I *think* I know what you mean, but I'd rather not risk changing the intent with an edit.

Comment: i think it is clear, to define an escalation after tags isn't enough to clarify what the user wants. feel free to edit i can always revise it

Comment: I have often found that no matter how explicit I am in my question in the SO universe, someone finds a way to provide an answer that is completely off-point. I just wanted to know if it's bad form to tell people, "Don't answer with this". You appear to confirm that it is NOT bad form.

Comment: @CigarDoug - that's people for you, not the "SO universe" only. No matter how hard you try, sometimes you will be misunderstood / the responder had one cup of coffee too many / too little, etc. Yes, the usual policy (at least around here) that it's not at all bad to specify the kind of responses you do not want (I'd say if done properly, it's encouraged).

Answer (score 12):

Yes.

You should clearly restrict your question in which answers are appropriate by being clear what you need, not iterating what you don't need.

If you need a latex paint color, say *I need a latex paint color*, and ideally add some context if it's a strange request or often solved in a way that's not applicable here, e.g. *because other paints like acrylic don't stick well to my wall*.

Don't go *I need a latex paint color, so not an acrylic one, also not water paint, also not ...* since it's both noise and either you formulated your question ambiguously and that's why you need to specify what you don't want, or it's patronizing and you assume people didn't read your question properly.

Comment: I tried to give a generic example as my basic question was, is it OK to say "I don't need these kind of answers". My overall experience with SO is that I should except answers that are unhelpful. If I asked about COLORS, the type of paint is irrelevant, since I specifically said, "colors".