# Are homework questions that do not allow use of built-in methods valid questions

Tags: discussion, homework

Is this kind of question a valid one on SO:

> I have a homework to write a code that do XXX but without using YY
>   built-in method because our mentor denied that or because we did not
>   get to the chapter contain this built-in method yet.

Assuming that the OP put what was tried so far and the question is well organized

Comment: Teachers are very good at asking a student to use the worst possible practice.  It is never *about* the practice, getting a student to think for himself instead of him asking somebody else to do the thinking for him is a never-ending battle.  This technique is a pretty good one.  Surely you see that advocating a fellow programmer to use the worst possible practice does not make for good Q+A and does not belong here.  Heaven forbid we get a lot of it and googlers start to assume it is thus a good practice.  VTC with anything in reach.

Comment: ^^^ 'I can't use arrays/strings/standard lib/loops/whatever...' DCV.

Comment: Worst: 'We can't use a debugger because our prof does not teach that till next semester and so, until then, I'm going to continue to post pages of crap to SO'.

Comment: This question is more specific than http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266979/contrived-homework-questions

Comment: Such questions may not be very useful to the general audience, especially if in practice one would solve XX by YY in most of the cases. One could consider downvoting them.

Comment: "Duplicate", where the top answer says treat such posts as too localized. Aha, so we just close the questions as too localized! Hmm now where did that close reason go... oh that's right, we removed it since SO had too high quality and standards back then. Lower quality means more crap questions, more crap questions means more traffic, more traffic means more cash. It all makes sense, embrace the crap!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not? How is it any different than this question:

> I need to write a function that computes the product of two floating-point values. However, I am developing this for an embedded system that lacks a hardware floating-point unit, so all floating-point operations have to be emulated in software. Obviously, this is slow, and performance profiling indicates that this is a serious bottleneck in my application.
>
> I have so far written the following implementation:
>
> ```
> float Multiply(float a, float b)
> { ... }
> ```
>
> But it does not correctly handle NaN values. How can I fix this code so that it handles NaN values? Are there any further optimizations that I can make so it runs even faster without sacrificing correctness?

Granted, seemingly arbitrary constraints are frustrating, but as long as they are stated up-front in the question and as long as the question meets our other guidelines, it doesn't make the question unacceptable.

Stated differently, it doesn't matter one whit whether the person is doing a homework assignment or writing code for the space shuttle. What matters is whether they've asked a coherent question that can be reasonably answered.

Comment: "it doesn't matter one whit whether the person is doing a homework assignment or writing code for the space shuttle" I disagree. The latter is likely to be a highly technical question that invites answers and comments from experts in the field, and as such is extremely valuable to the site. The former is almost certainly a very specific, once-off question that is trivial for anyone with basic programming skill to answer, and as such is just more noise. Yes, both questions may be answerable, but the quality is going to differ significantly.

Comment: Well, the question here was "are they valid questions?" I'm saying that they are valid. I agree that they are not particularly useful or interesting questions, and that outsourcing your homework to Stack Overflow is not especially educational, but I don't see these as reasons to deem such questions off-topic. @ian

Comment: @IanKemp You're implying that the site is (at least partly) here for the enjoyment of those of us who like answering challenging, technical questions, and not just for the googlers who want a quick fix for their homework assignments!

Comment: @IanKemp Yes, but lack of research / usefulness is a downvote reason. Whether that makes it "valid" is up to what one thinks this word may mean in the context, Cody Gray seems to think it means "on-topic" on which I agree.

Comment: There's quite a difference between "I cannot use float numbers because this is a small embedded system with no FPU" (real world problem with a sound rationale, using software floating point libraries on such systems is very bad practice) and "I cannot use float numbers to calculate this trigonometry equation because my teacher says so" (doesn't make any sense whatsoever, artificial requirements).

Answer (score 10):

I saw a Java homework recently that needed to handle a list of things, and the OP had been disallowed the use of arrays and collections, but didn't know why. Restrictions of this kind are usually the result of an instructor wanting the student to demonstrate knowledge of a particular technique other than the obvious ones.

In such cases, it could be argued that the question is not very useful, and that it could be closed as being too localised. However, since it is edge-case I think I would just comment, and ask the OP to find out the purpose of the restriction and/or ask them to find out what kinds of solution *are* acceptable to them.

Thus, homework constraints are themselves fine, but if the OP doesn't know why they have been applied, it may be a kindness to ask them to clarify this with their educator. Answers that come in before they have been clarified may be a waste of time, since they will turn out to be "unacceptable" as well.

Comment: Being too localized does not exist as close reason, but downvoting because these question are not very useful is about right, I would say.

Comment: @Trilarion: it used to exist as a close reason, and if it is a good fit I think it can still be used as a custom close reason.

Answer (score 4):

I personally think that all such questions are actively harmful both to the individual and the software industry as whole. Teachers should teach how to do things correctly. They should not teach how do avoid doing things correctly. Thinking outside the box is good - using a hammer for fixating a screw is not.

The repeated use of such artificial requirements by bad teachers has caused lots of those ugly work-arounds to become commonly used in production code, where they are actively causing harm every day.

Some examples from C/C++ programming, where such academia bad practice have also become common production code practice:

- Using obscure series of operators instead of the most readable version (like using bitwise operators instead of the `+ - * /` operators, or using XOR operator for byte swapping).
- Using recursion for things that could be trivially solved with loops.
- Using function-like macros for no reason, instead of proper functions.
- Excessive use of the `?:` operator in places where it leads to less readable code than `if-else`.
- Using global variables instead of changing the definition of function parameters.
- Using spaghetti keywords like `goto` or  `continue` instead of plain loops.
- And so on, I can go on forever.

**We might have to wake up and realize that SO is a major culprit in spreading such bad practice.**

This is because of the site design. You aren't allowed to question the rationale of the OP. If you do, and post an example of how things actually should be properly done, you will get down voted and maybe even flagged as NAA. This for teaching people good practice and industry standard programming, making the software world better.

As an example, take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745385/c-hardcoded-array-as-memcpy-parameter/35746852#35746852) by yours sincerely. It has gotten 8 down votes because "it doesn't answer the question". I posted it as a "counter-example", since the question requirements didn't make any sense and following them would lead to bad practice. Not only making the OP a worse programmer, but also making every beginner who would encounter the post in the future a worse programmer too. (It would give the person reading the question and answers a misconception of how compilers actually translate and optimize code, causing them to obfuscate their code to gain some imaginary performance.)

So I fully support a policy change where questions with artificial requirements are made off-topic. SO should be a high quality site that you can turn to when you wonder how things should be done properly. Answers that teach good programming practice should be encouraged, not frowned upon.

Comment: I'll go for that.   I have been DCVing 'drive a nail without using a hammer' questions since forever, and will continue to do so.  It's not that they are of no value to future SO users, they are of negative value:(

Comment: Great answer. 100% agrre with you

Comment: Obviously, questions with 'real' constraints, (I have on 8k RAM on my controller, I can not link a FP library), should remain:)

Comment: I think there is a distinction to be made between (A) banning these types of questions and (B) banning answers that advocate for "a better idea." The problem here is not that the person asked the question, but rather that people are downvoting your answer. I guess that requires too much of a culture change, people would have to turn on their brains when evaluating the quality of answers, rather than just pattern matching with words in the question.

Comment: "If you do, and post an example of how things actually should be properly done, you will get down voted and maybe even flagged as NAA"  Although, I will answer the right answer IMO and not the constrained one and I do not care about downvoting. I start to believe that it is a habit here for lot of users. They just downvote what they did not like not what is not correct.

Comment: "You aren't allowed to question the rationale of the OP" labelling a question as an XY Problem is doing just that.

Comment: "You aren't allowed to question the rationale of the OP. If you do, and post an example of how things actually should be properly done, you will get down voted and maybe even flagged as NAA. This for teaching people good practice and industry standard programming, making the software world better." - That's a good point. Obviously the Q&A approach is a bit conflicting with the "teaching high standards" goal. Sometimes the question is just a bad one.

Comment: Also related: really obscure, very bad practice questions tend to get up-voted out of proportion. Some of the most up-voted questions for C and C++ are [the ??!??! operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do) and [the --> operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator). All of it complete nonsense, you shouldn't write code like that, you will never encounter such code outside jokes and obfuscation contests, and knowing the reason why it works will not make you a better programmer, but possibly a worse one.

Comment: Seems it all boils down to the need for a site dedicated to real-world programming Q&A for professionals only. I would really love to have such a site: I would abandon SO instantly in favour for it.

Comment: a site for beginners where it is required to explain the answer properly and thoroughly (which could include "real life" practises too), may be benefitical too

Comment: Overall, I think everyone would benefit from 2 different sites, one for beginners and one for professionals. The beginners would get a more tolerant site, where answers are always in plain English with simple code. And the professions would get a quality site with a whole lot less crap, homework questions and duplicates.

Comment: @Lundin seems a proposal like that got refused in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95458/stack-overflow-beginner) so this idea may have no chance

Answer (score 3):

This is **meant** to be site for "professional and enthusiast programmers". Would a professional or enthusiast ever post such a question? If not, the question **must** be off topic, and the only uncertainty would be which close reason to use.

A professional would never ask such a question. They would not waste their time implementing functionality available through all practical versions of  the standard library of their language.  They *might* ask a how to do something without using functionality provided by a new version of the standard library, because it is not yet practical for them to upgrade.

An enthusiast might want to code some functionality available in their standard library, as a personal challenge or to deepen their understanding. But they would make considerable effort themself; they would post a debugging question, and the code would not be riddled with errors,  questionable constructs and poor style.

So questions about how to do something without using functionality provided by the standard library *can* be on topic. Except the on topic cases look *nothing like* a typical homework question of this form. The specifics of the question are different; the work done by the poster is more extensive and better; the question will be about code that has similar functionality to the standard library (it might even have the same interface). So no, I do not think these kinds of homework question are on topic.

Comment: The meaning of "enthusiast programmer" is unfortunately very broad. What if the poster is very eager and positive, but post a trash question? As long as they are enthusiastic and the question is about programming, any trash is welcomed on the site. SO is in turn eager and enthusiastic to be an interactive beginner tutorial, as much as a Q&A site for real-world programming questions. And that's why beginner-level questions with artificial requirements are often welcomed. SO has too broad a scope.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that we [deprecated the homework tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) was because the context of homework isn't absolutely needed in a question that deals with an odd set of constraints - it should just be like any other question that deals with an odd set of constraints.

It's perfectly fine for someone to preemptively say it's an assignment because they realize how ludicrous their endeavor might sound otherwise - *why the heck aren't you just using the built in method?!* - we're good there.

As long as the question is thoughtful and not simply asking someone to do their [home]work for them as a service, there's nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: Yes, lots of changes were made over the years. And because of them, SO is a much worse site now than it was a couple of years ago, when homework questions had their own tag, and we had "must demonstrate minimal knowledge" and "too localized" close reasons. Over the years since those changes were made, the quality of the site has decreased notably.